# Where I can find saved file in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I have weblogic in localhost. My web application save some rdf:

```
String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
FileOutputStream fop = null;
try {
    fop = new FileOutputStream(name);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

}
model.write(fop);
```

When I go to the url where is this file saved I got this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://url/0260fcff-b53d-4d18-8fb0-fb31f6a6ff1a.rdf
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Where I can find this file in my computer ?

PS I try to save this file with just java application and it works so rdf should be OK.

Comment: Did you `close` the file stream? (That's not in the code snippet)

Comment: nope but I add this but the result is same but thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you save a file without specifying the path, the file is saved at a location from where **your JVM is invoked**. For web applications this is typically the **bin folder**. So please check that location (e.g. for tomcat it would be {TOMCAT_HOME}/bin)
2. The way you are accessing the file (`http://url/0260fcff-b53d-4d18-8fb0-fb31f6a6ff1a.rdf)` you are expecting it in the root of your web application. 
   For example, if you have a tomcat based application say myapp.war the root of your web app would be `{TOMCAT_HOME}/webapp/myapp`
3. This is the reason the generated file is not found when accessed via a URL.
4. **To make it work**, specify a path (absolute path) to the file input stream (create a File object with desired path location, in this case it would be `{TOMCAT_HOME}/webapp/myapp`)

Comment: can you also write here how I can find {TOMCAT_HOME} in my web application ? t

Comment: Its the installation dir of the tomcat server.

Comment: yes I know but I cant set string in application path = "/../../" because when I deploy this application to other system then it stops work

Comment: Got your problem. The way out is. Set an environment variable with the value as root of your webapp (e.g. `APP_ROOT=c:\tomcat\webapp\myapp`) and use `System.getenv("APP_ROOT")` to get its value in your code. Make sure that you set this env variable before you start your application.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(new File("."))` would give you the path. But you should avoid relative paths. Configure an absolute path for your application and use that.

Also note that you wouldn't normally store files in the application itself. You store them in a separate location, and server them to clients via a special controller that reads them and streams them back.

Comment: nice I found it and everything seems be ok so I dont know why I got still this error but this is another question so thx a lot